# Page Title not showing fully in Xamarin.Forms page

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, toolbar, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.

I am adding 2 toolbar items to a Xamarin.Form page in my iOS App

```cs
var tbiAdd = new ToolbarItem("Add", "AddIcon.png", async () => {        
    //Goto different page         
});

var tbiFilter = new ToolbarItem("Filter", "FilterArrowDownImage.png", async () => {
    //Goto different page        
});
```

I have the page title set "Product & Services"

The title is showing as "Product & Ser..".
Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like your title is just too long?, and getting truncated?

Comment: when button title is text that is coming correct.
Why it is taking unnecessary space when toolBarButton contains Image ??

Comment: How did you add the drop down button in the title?